# More precisse shape or mask for a SKSpriteNode object

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I'm bulding a simple application using **SpriteKit for iOS 7 / 8** but I'm having some issues with my sprites when I try to touch and launch some events from one of two nodes that are too close to each other.

When I try to touch one of them, I end up touching the upper layer one square mask, and if I change the `[self addChaild:]` order it happens the same but with the other one.

[image: Overlapped SKSpriteNode]

I want to know if I can create a more precisse mask for my nodes so this won happen when I try to touch them. I know I can create a physics world and a physics body for each of them to control **Collision Detection** but I don't know if this is the right approach.

BTW... I'm using the methods `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` for touching events detection.

**PD:** if you need any more info about my implementation please let me know.